# panel regression with country group year fixed effects

Tags: stata, panel

For my research, I need to do multiple FE with panel data.

the dependent variable is group-level, Independent variables is country level.

So I tried

```
reg y x i.group i.country i.year
```

The response was not sorted, can't proceed.

Only in this circumstance is it possible to proceed:

```
egen ID = group(country group)
xtset ID year
reg y x i.group i.year i.country
```

I am not sure if I wrote the right code.

Comment: Your `regress` call is unaffected by your `xtset` settings.  What was the _exact_ error message. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for advice on asking a good question.